# How to use generics defined in @types for a react native library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to use the Agenda component from [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) library in Typescript. The issue I have been facing is that the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native-calendars/index.d.ts) makes heavy use of generics mainly `TItem` to define types for various parameters. When I need to call functions that makes use of this generic the Typescript compiler in VSCode complains that the parameter is defined as `any` due to which I cannot use all the goodness of TS and I do not know how to incorporate these generics in my code.

```
<Agenda
  items={state.items}
  loadItemsForMonth={loadItems.bind(this)}
  selected={'2017-05-16'}
  renderItem={renderItem.bind(this)}
  renderEmptyDate={renderEmptyDate.bind(this)}
  rowHasChanged={rowHasChanged.bind(this)}
  showClosingKnob={true}
/>

function renderItem(item) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => Alert.alert(item.name)}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

The compiler complains `Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.` The `item` parameter in `renderItem` is supposed to be a `TItem` but how do I tell the compiler this?

Comment: What's the type of `state.items`?

Comment: `items` is a react state object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TItem` is the name of the generic type `@types/react-native-calendars` used. [It has no meaning outside it being generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

What you actually want is to tell the compiler that the argument of `renderItem` is of your type.

For example, if your `item` type is `Foo`:

```
function renderItem(item: Foo) {
```

Comment: so does this mean that I need to `console.log` each parameter, see what the library is passing in to the function and then design `interfaces` accordingly?

Comment: You already have the interface. `state.items` should be an array of that interface